# How to merge List of Maps of Maps into a Map of Maps?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

Could you help me with `Java Streams`?

As you can see from the title I need to merge `List<Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>>>` into `Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>>`.

The list is represented as `List<Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>>>` and looks like:

```
[  
   {  
      "USER_1":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":1,
            "totalGenuine":1,
            "totalDevelopment":1
         }
      },
      "USER_2":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":1,
            "totalGenuine":1,
            "totalDevelopment":1
         },
         "APP_2":{  
            "total":2,
            "totalGenuine":2,
            "totalDevelopment":2
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "USER_1":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":1,
            "totalGenuine":1,
            "totalDevelopment":1
         }
      },
      "USER_2":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":1,
            "totalGenuine":1,
            "totalDevelopment":1
         },
         "APP_2":{  
            "total":2,
            "totalGenuine":2,
            "totalDevelopment":2
         }
      }
   }
]
```

So, as you can see, duplicate keys could be everywhere. 
My goal is to combine them into `Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>>` by merging `Genuineness`. Merge `Genuineness` simply means return a new object with summed up values `total`, `totalGenuine`, and `totalDevelopment`.

Here is my implementation that fails:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>> map = taskHandles.stream().map(this::mapTaskHandle)
                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                .collect(
                                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                g -> new Genuineness(g.getValue().getTotal(), g.getValue().getTotalGenuine(), g.getValue().getTotalDevelopment()),
                                                (g1, g2) -> new Genuineness(g1.getTotal() + g2.getTotal(),
                                                        g1.getTotalGenuine() + g2.getTotalGenuine(),
                                                        g1.getTotalDevelopment() + g2.getTotalGenuine()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                );
```

It fails with message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key {TEST_33_33_APP_1=live.attach.billing.domain.model.billing.Genuineness@951b6fe}
```

So, seems that in my implementation I've pointed how to combine inner map but didn't make a merging of values of outer map and I don't know how to do it.

I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
Expected output:

```
   {  
      "USER_1":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":2,
            "totalGenuine":2,
            "totalDevelopment":2
         }
      },
      "USER_2":{  
         "APP_1":{  
            "total":2,
            "totalGenuine":2,
            "totalDevelopment":2
         },
         "APP_2":{  
            "total":4,
            "totalGenuine":4,
            "totalDevelopment":4
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output, otherwise it's almost impossible to find out what you're after

Comment: Consider using the flatMap feature of java streams.  It will break down a layered collection for you into a flat stream of objects.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I've added expected output and simplified input data

Comment: I would highly recommend moving the merge logic of two `Genuineness` objects into the `Genuineness` class, e.g. add a `Genuineness merge(Genuineness other)` method that returns a new merged `Genuineness` object. It will simplify your code and make it a lot easier later on if you need to add another field to `Genuineness` that also needs to be merged. Basically, make `Genuineness` responsible to knowing how to merge two (or more) instances of itself, i.e. putting the logic where it belongs.

Comment: Is it a good pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, this is a horrible data structure to work with and the maintainers of this code will have a hard time finding out problems that arise.

You should take a step back and consider refactoring the code, any way you can solve the missing part by using the following merge function in the outmost `toMap`:

```
(l, r) -> {
      r.forEach((k, v) -> l.merge(k, v,
                    (bi, bii) -> new Genuineness(bi.getTotal() + bii.getTotal(),
                               bi.getTotalGenuine() + bii.getTotalGenuine(),
                               bi.getTotalDevelopment() + bii.getTotalGenuine())));
       return l;
}
```

Full code:

```
taskHandles.stream().map(this::mapTaskHandle)
                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                .collect(
                                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                g -> new Genuineness(g.getValue().getTotal(), g.getValue().getTotalGenuine(), g.getValue().getTotalDevelopment()),
                                                (g1, g2) -> new Genuineness(g1.getTotal() + g2.getTotal(),
                                                        g1.getTotalGenuine() + g2.getTotalGenuine(),
                                                        g1.getTotalDevelopment() + g2.getTotalGenuine()
                                                )
                                        )
                                ),(l, r) -> {
                                  r.forEach((k, v) -> l.merge(k, v,
                                          (bi, bii) -> new Genuineness(bi.getTotal() + bii.getTotal(),
                                                  bi.getTotalGenuine() + bii.getTotalGenuine(),
                                                  bi.getTotalDevelopment() + bii.getTotalGenuine())));
                                  return l;
                                }

                        )
                );
```

**[Ideone](https://ideone.com/ABFUMP)**

Comment: (+1) was looking into a similar solution from a previous problem which was stated as map-reduction by the OP in one of the threads.

Answer (score 3):

Though [Aomine's suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563926/1746118) seems to be correct, you can alternatively improve your code readability and simplify it defining a [`BinaryOperator<Genuineness>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) as :

```
BinaryOperator<Genuineness> remappingGenuineness = (g1, g2) -> new Genuineness(g1.getTotal() + g2.getTotal(),
        g1.getTotalGenuine() + g2.getTotalGenuine(),
        g1.getTotalDevelopment() + g2.getTotalGenuine()
);
```

and then further use it as :

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Genuineness>> map = taskHandles.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, remappingGenuineness)),
                (a, b) -> {
                    a.forEach((k, v) -> b.merge(k, v, remappingGenuineness));
                    return b;
                }));
```

Comment: Yeah looks a good improvement so far, I didn't really think too much into refactoring OP's code as solving the problem alone took some good energy out of me. +1